# Why does shell builtin colon command ":" after variable assignment on same line cause empty string value to be assigned?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, variable-assignment, built-in

If I add the `colon` (`:`) builtin shell command after an assignment, the variable gets assigned to the empty string (`""`).  Why does it behave like that?  I expected it to have no effect.

```sh
    set -vx
    MyVar1='my var 1'  : colon comment here  # *** !!! This gets assigned to empty string!!!
    MyVar2='my var 2'  # hash comment here; this is fine

    echo "MyVar1 = [$MyVar1]"  # EXPECTED: 'my var 1'; ACTUAL: '' (empty string).  Why?
    echo "MyVar2 = [$MyVar2]"  # As expected.
```

> : (a colon)
>   : [arguments]
>   Do nothing beyond expanding arguments and performing redirections. The return status is zero.
>   https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html

Comment: It isn't actually empty, it is not set (try `[[ -v $MyVar1 ]] || echo 'not set'` as a test).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`:` is a built-in command which returns successfully (a shorthand version of `true`).

When you do a variable assignment on the same line as a command, the assignment is only valid for the duration of the command (this is typically used to run commands with temporary environment variables set).

So when you run:

```
MyVar1='my var 1'  : colon comment here
```

You are:

- running the command `:`
- passing arguments `colon`, `comment` and `here` (these are dropped by the command)
- with the *temporary* variable assignment `MyVar1='my var 1'` (this has no effect on the command)

This behaviour is described in [the spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_01):

> A "simple command" is a sequence of optional variable assignments and redirections, in any sequence, optionally followed by words and redirections, terminated by a control operator.
>
> ...
>
> If no command name results, variable assignments shall affect the current execution environment. Otherwise, the variable assignments shall be exported for the execution environment of the command and shall not affect the current execution environment (except for special built-ins).

As pointed out in the comments (thanks!), [`:` *is* one of the *special built-ins*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14), which means that in a standards-compliant shell, the assignment should affect the current execution environment. By default, Bash doesn't comply with the spec in this sense, although you can make it do so by invoking it as `sh` (on systems where it is the default shell) or by using `bash --posix`:

```
$ bash -c 'foo=bar :; echo $foo'

$ sh -c 'foo=bar :; echo $foo'
bar
$ bash --posix -c 'foo=bar :; echo $foo'
bar
```

Comment: So you are saying that anything *before* the colon (`:`) command is essentially ignored?

Comment: Any variable assignments before a command only affect the execution environment of the command (in your case, `:`), not the current execution environment (the shell).

Comment: Note this behavior is non-standard. According to the POSIX spec, `:` is a *special* built-in, and variable assignment that precede a special are supposed to remain in effect after the command completes. If you invoke `bash` as `sh` or with the `--posix` option, the OP's expected behavior is observed.

Comment: @RobBednark A common example where you would want a temporary assignment is with the `read` command. `IFS=, read a b c` will read a line of input, split it on commas, and assign the first three fields to `a`, `b, and `c`. The global value of `IFS` remains unaffected, though.

Comment: (See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14)